# How to fix "Nothing to do" error on openproject configure?

Tags: centos, openproject

I am installing OpenProject 8.3.1 on my apache 2.4 CentOS7 WHM/CPanel VPS using packaged installation and I've run into the following problem:

When I run `openproject configure` right  after installation process it goes well up until the line "No package mod_ssl available". Followed by "Error: Nothing to do". Openproject can't be accessed.

I'm using PostgreSQL and auto installation/configuration option. I've tried skipping all but the most essential options in configuration, to no help.

The mod_ssl unavailable bit is the most surprising, since after I run `rpm -qa|grep mod_ssl` I get "ea-apache24-mod_ssl-2.4.38-3.3.1.cpanel.x86_64" - meaning I in fact **do have** mod_ssl available.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using a non-standard CentOS edition with CPanel. I don't think OpenProject can be installed on such a distribution, because it seems to come with limitations as to what packages are available. The mod_ssl package you mention is the one originally distributed by the CentOS distribution.

Comment: Actually that is also what I gathered so far. I've updated the question to include information that it's about cpanel running server.